# ucanaccess 3.0.2 still returning column names in uppercase

Tags: ucanaccess

my access .accdb databases have column names in mixed case. I put ucanaccess 3.0.2 in my class library (with the dependent libraries that came with ucanaccess) in NetBeans.  I'm getting the error that says object not found with the column name in all caps. Is there a switch I need to add to the connection string to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

After closing the project and reopening, the case problem has resolved itself.

Comment: Something was still dirty...I like this kind of self-made solutions.